# Accessing the contextMenu of a spark TextInput component

Tags: apache-flex, contextmenu, textinput, flex-spark

How can I add custom context menu items to the context menu of a spark TextInput component? I am using Flex 4.5.1.

Assuming I have a spark TextInput called `sparktext`:

```
trace(sparktext.contextMenu) // returns null
trace(sparktext.textDisplay.contextMenu) // returns null
```

Since those returned null, I though I would just create a contextMenu using:

```
sparktext.contextMenu = new ContextMenu()
//add entries
```

Or

```
sparktext.textDisplay.contextMenu = new ContextMenu()
//add entries
```

Now a contextMenu is created. But the created context menu is a "flash" context menu, displaying items like "play", "zoom" and so on. I have lost entries for items like "copy", "paste" and so on.

I have tried creating a `RichEditableText`, and its `contextMenu` property actually contains a `ContextMenu` object. I am at lost as to why the `RichEditableText` object, which is stored in `TextInput.textDisplay` does not contain a `ContextMenu` object in its `contextMenu` property.

Can anyone shed some light on this and how I can ADD context menu items to the context menu of a TextInput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still couldn't work out why `sparktext.textDisplay.contextMenu` is `NULL`.

But here's what I did:

```
var testmenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
testmenu.hideBuiltInItems();
testmenu.clipboardMenu = true; //Use this to show the options such as copy, paste and so on.
sparktext.textDisplay.contextMenu = testmenu;
```